# Code Igniter returning an especific inserted value

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, codeigniter

In PostgreSQL I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_cardbrand (cardbrand_name) VALUES ("Ferrari") RETURNING cardbrand_id;
```

I want to know if it is possible to implement it using Code Igniter 3, I need the "`cardbrand_id`" and I can not use `$this->db->insert_id();` for particular reasons of the database's model.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible..

Since you specified you don't wanna to use `$this->db->insert_id();` so you can use this query

`select MAX(cardbrand_id) from tbl_cardbrand`

this cause one more hit to database but it will retrieve your currently inserted `cardbrand_id`

Note:- I considered `cardbrand_id` to be *Auto-Incremented*

Comment: Hi! The problem here is I'm not autoincrementing the ID using serial or integers. I have the FK in other table, so "last_id" won't work neither. I need the use of "returning".